# using Java reflection feature in Android app

Tags: android

hey, does anyone have experience in developing Android app with Java reflection feature?

I am stuck with a peculiar problem , looking for help.

I have a Activity and a common class residing in the same package of my Activity,
let's assume they are com.mypkg.MyActivity and com.mypkg.MyClass
my code in MyActivity:

```
Class clazz = MyClass.class;
Constructor[] constructors1 = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
Class cls = java.lang.Object.class;
Constructor[] constructors2 = cls.getDeclaredConstructors();
...
```

okay, now my problem:
the code runs fine on simulator, 
while on real device, constructors of those pre-built classes, such as java.lang.Object or android.widget.FrameLayout, can be retrieved correctly, but constructors of MyClass is always empty(i.e. constructors1.length is always zero)

I am very confused, any help?

Comment: Any difference if you get a reference to your class via Class.forName("your class name")?

Comment: thanks for reply, I also tried the Class.forName , it ran the same result as the MyClass.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be something you've tried, but are you sure your class (MyClass) is declared correctly in your AndroidManifest.xml? Perhaps your emulator is more lenient than an actual device.